# If $\| f(x) \| \leq \| x \|^{\alpha}$, for $\alpha > 1$ then f is differentiable in $p=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, show that if $\| f(x) \| \leq \| x \|^{\alpha}$, for $\alpha > 1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k$, then f is differentiable in $p=0$ with differential $df_0 = 0$.

I guess I'd simply have to show that:

$$ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\| f(x+h)-f(x) \|}{\|h\|} =\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\| f(h)-f(0) \|}{\|h\|} = 0$$,

but I'm not sure how to do this and I don't know how the inequality is supposed to be of any help. Any hints?

Comment: How about the triangle inequality?

Comment: what is $p$????

Comment: @5xum I would get a greater than inequality by using the triangle inequality, wouldn't I? $\|f(h)-f(0)\| \geq \| \|f(h)\| - \|f(0)\| \|$, I don't see how this would be of any help.

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam $p=0$, a point in $\mathbb{R}^k$, as it was stated in the question.

Comment: @eager2learn Yes, but you also get $||f(h) - f(0)|| \leq ||f(h))|| + ||f(0)||$. And you can use the inequality to calculate what $f(0)$ is equal to.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is pretty much it. The inequality gives $f(0) = 0$. So: $$0 \leq \frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|} \leq \|h\|^{\alpha - 1} \implies 0 \leq \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|} \leq 0 \implies \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0, $$ because $\alpha - 1 > 0$.